# kernel module doesn't search for include library when -I is used

Tags: c, gcc, makefile, kernel-module

I want to build a basic `main.c`, that is actually a kernel module written in C. I have include header files that are in `include/`. I want to use GCC `-I` to make GCC search for the include headers in `-Iinclude`. However, GCC doesn't seem to understand that, and I have no clue how to debug it.

Tree:

```
main.c
include
   file.h
```

main.c

```c
#include "file.h"
...
```

Makefile:

```
EXTRA_CFLAGS += -Iinclude -Werror -Wall \
                -Wno-missing-braces -Wno-error=unused-function

all:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules

clean:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) clean
```

The error:

```c
main.c: fatal error: file.h: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because make is not actually running in your directory, when it compiles things.

The `-C` option in this command:

```
make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules
```

tells make to change it's current working directory to that path.  Thus, `include` is no longer the `include` directory in your current directory.

You should write it like this:

```
EXTRA_CFLAGS += -I'$M/include' -Werror -Wall \
                -Wno-missing-braces -Wno-error=unused-function

all:
        $(MAKE) -C "/lib/modules/$$(uname -r)/build" M='$(CURDIR)' modules

clean:
        $(MAKE) -C "/lib/modules/$$(uname -r)/build" M='$(CURDIR)' clean
```

You should always use `$(MAKE)`, and never `make`, when running a sub-make.  And using make's `shell` function is not really needed since a recipe is already running in a shell.  And, `PWD` is just inherited from the calling shell and might be inaccurate.

Comment: This doens't work. `CURDIR` _does_ work and point to the right directory, it should find `include`, however it still won't find the header file. `main.c` is still not able to find `file.h`

Comment: Please make sure you're using my latest edits.  You should be using `$M` in the `EXTRA_CFLAGS`.

Comment: Damn, it worked when I changed `CURDIR` to `M`. Why is that? `CURDIR` _does_ point to my current working directory, that is my tree.

Comment: When you run the top-level make, `CURDIR` is your directory.  But, as I said, you're invoking a sub-make in a different directory and that sub-make is doing all the work.  In that sub-make, `CURDIR` is set to the working directory of the sub-make, not your directory.  That's why you set `M=$(CURDIR)` on the sub-make command line so that in the sub-make the variable `M` is set to your directory; whenever you want to talk about your directory you use `$M`.